# A simple group by

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

The question is that List the SUPPLIER_ID, supplier NAME and the number of products each supplier has provided. List only those that have supplied more than 2 products. [Use PRODUCT and SUPPLIER tables]

```
SELECT  S.SUPPLIER_ID, S.NAME, COUNT(S.PRODUCT_ID)
FROM PRODUCT P, SUPPLIER S
WHERE P.SUPPLIER_ID = S.SUPPLIER_ID
GROUP BY NAME;

SELECT SUPPLIER_ID,  COUNT(PRODUCT_ID)
FROM SUPPLIER, PRODUCT
WHERE  SUPPLIER.SUPPLIER_ID = PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_ID
GROUP BY NAME;
```

I tried the both ways, but they won't work. What are problems?

Answer (score 2):

First, learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax with the join conditions in the `ON` clause.

This is particularly important if you are learning SQL.

Second, your problem is that you have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  So, I imagine this is the query you want:

```
SELECT  S.SUPPLIER_ID, S.NAME, COUNT(S.PRODUCT_ID)
FROM PRODUCT P JOIN
     SUPPLIER S
     ON P.SUPPLIER_ID = S.SUPPLIER_ID
GROUP BY S.SUPPLIER_ID, S.NAME
HAVING COUNT(S.PRODUCT_ID) > 1;
```

You need the `HAVING` clause to ensure that there are at least two products per supplier.

Comment: Also, I will use always join syntax for next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
SELECT S.SUPPLIER_ID, S.NAME, COUNT(S.PRODUCT_ID)
FROM PRODUCT P, SUPPLIER S 
WHERE P.SUPPLIER_ID = S.SUPPLIER_ID
GROUP BY  S.SUPPLIER_ID, S.NAME;
```

Basically if you are aggregating a column, you should provide all the columns in a select query in a group by clause

Comment: Using JOINS provides good permanence compared to WHERE clause. So keep practicing using JOINS while having condition

Comment: Thank you for your explanation for group by.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  S.SUPPLIER_ID, S.NAME, COUNT(S.PRODUCT_ID) COUNTER
FROM PRODUCT P, SUPPLIER S
WHERE P.SUPPLIER_ID = S.SUPPLIER_ID
GROUP BY S.SUPPLIER_ID,S.NAME
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  S.SUPPLIER_ID, S.NAME, COUNT(P.PRODUCT_ID)
FROM PRODUCT P JOIN
     SUPPLIER S
     ON P.SUPPLIER_ID = S.SUPPLIER_ID
GROUP BY S.SUPPLIER_ID, S.NAME 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can make this answer better by [edit]ing it to explain how it works.